# Как сделать парсинг csv файла с двойными кавычками, в которых находится список, в List<MyClass> с помощью openCSV Java?

Tags: java, csv

Пример csv файла:

```
Marianna Villalobos,38,"Web,Android"
Sanah Jacobs,41,"Java,Python,iOS"
Romany Burnett,36,"Web,Python"
```

Мой класс:

```java
public class StudentPOJO {

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private String name;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private int age;
    @CsvBindAndJoinByPosition(position = "2", elementType = String.class)
    private List<String> courses;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Пытаюсь получить `List<StudentPOJO>`:

```
List<StudentPOJO> students = new CsvToBeanBuilder<StudentPOJO>(new FileReader(FILE_PATH))
                .withType(StudentPOJO.class)
                .build()
                .parse();
```

ошибка в строке ".build()":

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-4" java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException: Conversion of
> Web,Python to java.util.List failed.  at
> com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:103)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) Caused by:
> com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException: Conversion of
> Web,Python to java.util.List failed.  at
> com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.convertToRead(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:95)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.BeanFieldSingleValue.convert(BeanFieldSingleValue.java:91)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.setFieldValue(AbstractBeanField.java:169)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.setFieldValue(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:449)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:317)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:134)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:87)
> ... 3 more Caused by:
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Can't convert value
> 'Web,Python' to type interface java.util.List     at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.conversionException(AbstractConverter.java:474)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.StringConverter.convertToType(StringConverter.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.convert(AbstractConverter.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ConverterFacade.convert(ConverterFacade.java:61)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:491)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.convertToRead(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:86)
> ... 9 more Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2"
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException: Conversion of
> Web,Android,iOS to java.util.List failed.     at
> com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:103)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) Caused by:
> com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException: Conversion of
> Web,Android,iOS to java.util.List failed.     at
> com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.convertToRead(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:95)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.BeanFieldSingleValue.convert(BeanFieldSingleValue.java:91)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.setFieldValue(AbstractBeanField.java:169)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.setFieldValue(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:449)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:317)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:134)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:87)
> ... 3 more Caused by:
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Can't convert value
> 'Web,Android,iOS' to type interface java.util.List    at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.conversionException(AbstractConverter.java:474)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.StringConverter.convertToType(StringConverter.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.convert(AbstractConverter.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ConverterFacade.convert(ConverterFacade.java:61)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:491)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.convertToRead(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:86)
> ... 9 more Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3"
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException: Conversion of
> Web,Python,iOS to java.util.List failed.  at
> com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:103)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) Caused by:
> com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException: Conversion of
> Web,Python,iOS to java.util.List failed.  at
> com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.convertToRead(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:95)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.BeanFieldSingleValue.convert(BeanFieldSingleValue.java:91)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField.setFieldValue(AbstractBeanField.java:169)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.setFieldValue(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:449)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:317)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:134)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:87)
> ... 3 more Caused by:
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Can't convert value
> 'Web,Python,iOS' to type interface java.util.List     at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.conversionException(AbstractConverter.java:474)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.StringConverter.convertToType(StringConverter.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.convert(AbstractConverter.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.ConverterFacade.convert(ConverterFacade.java:61)
> at
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:491)
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.convertToRead(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:86)
> ... 9 more Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" Exception in thread
> "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing CSV line: 3. [Jesse
> Singh,23,Web,Android,iOS]     at
> com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:365)  at
> Main.main(Main.java:22)

Comment: классический csv содержит в качестве разделителся полей точку с запятой. подозреваю, что проблема именно  в этом, а не в кавычках.

Comment: @Дмитрий "классический csv содержит в качестве разделителся полей точку с запятой" - спорное утверждение. Если бы это было так, то формат бы назывался SCSV (semicolon separated values) а не CSV (comma separated valuse).

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно используете `CsvBindAndJoinByPosition`. Эта аннотация позволяет несколько колонок объединить в одну коллекцию. У вас же задача противоположная - нужно одну колонку со значениями отделенными запятыми разделить. То есть значение `Java,Python,iOS` из последней колонки нужно разделить.

Так что правильно будет так:

```
public class StudentPOJO {

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private String name;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private int age;
    @CsvBindAndSplitByPosition(position = 2, elementType = String.class, collectionType = LinkedList.class, splitOn = ",")
    private List<String> courses;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Roman огромное спасибо! Это именно то что мне нужно было. Только в "@CsvBindAndSplitByPosition(position = "2"," значение position надо без кавычек просто число.